# Is it possible to identify which feature maps were generated from a particular image after convolutional operation

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

Let's say I have a video that contains 3 grayscale sequential frames having a combined shape of (3, 24, 24). After inputting these frames together into a CNN, multiple feature maps will be generated from each of the images. Would it be possible for me to separate the temporal aspect by identifying which frame generated which feature maps?

Comment: Is $3$ your batch size?

Comment: Yes you could say that. Then the shape of my input would (3,1,24,24) => 3 images, 1 channel,  Height, Width. @hanugm